# Style specific path element in a svg in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I was wondering how could I style a specific path element in a whole svg imported as a component in react...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 850.39 773.76"><path d="M708.66,354.35C476.29,122,127.72,470.53,360.1,702.91l348.56,348.56,348.56-348.56C1289.6,470.53,941,122,708.66,354.35ZM1056.4,557.42c-6.14,32.85-23.71,64-52.21,92.46L708.66,945.41,413.13,649.88c-28.5-28.5-46.07-59.6-52.21-92.45-5.33-28.52-1.84-58.82,10.08-87.61,13.62-32.87,37.67-62.74,67.74-84.1,30.39-21.59,64.21-33,97.82-33,42.73,0,82.79,18.39,119.06,54.67l53,53,53-53C798,371.1,838,352.71,880.75,352.71c33.61,0,67.45,11.41,97.83,33,30.07,21.36,54.13,51.23,67.74,84.09C1058.25,498.6,1061.73,528.9,1056.4,557.42Z" transform="translate(-283.46 -277.71)"/><path class="likeInside" d="M413.13,649.88c-28.5-28.5-46.06-59.6-52.2-92.45-5.34-28.52-1.85-58.82,10.08-87.61,13.61-32.87,37.67-62.74,67.74-84.1,30.38-21.59,64.21-33,97.82-33,42.73,0,82.78,18.39,119.06,54.67l53,53,53-53C798,371.1,838,352.71,880.76,352.71c33.61,0,67.44,11.41,97.83,33,30.07,21.36,54.13,51.23,67.74,84.09,11.92,28.79,15.41,59.09,10.08,87.61-6.15,32.85-23.71,64-52.22,92.46L708.66,945.41Z" transform="translate(-283.46 -277.71)"/></svg>
```

I want to style the path with the class "likeInside"

my svg is imported and used like so :

```js
import {ReactComponent as Heart} from './heart2.svg'
```

And it's used like so:

```js
    <div className={styles.like}>
         <Heart className={styles.likeIcon}/>
    </div>
```

I am styling my element with css modules and I am not using classes to create my components (I am using arrow function).

Do you have any idea ? Thanks by advance !

Comment: You've got to crack open that SVG and import it as a piece of inline SVG. You cannot apply external styles to an .svg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Create a component and paste the svg code inside then add "className" in props ( don't forget className={className} )

**Heart.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Heart({ className }) {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 850.39 773.76">
      <path
        d="M708.66,354.35C476.29,122,127.72,470.53,360.1,702.91l348.56,348.56,348.56-348.56C1289.6,470.53,941,122,708.66,354.35ZM1056.4,557.42c-6.14,32.85-23.71,64-52.21,92.46L708.66,945.41,413.13,649.88c-28.5-28.5-46.07-59.6-52.21-92.45-5.33-28.52-1.84-58.82,10.08-87.61,13.62-32.87,37.67-62.74,67.74-84.1,30.39-21.59,64.21-33,97.82-33,42.73,0,82.79,18.39,119.06,54.67l53,53,53-53C798,371.1,838,352.71,880.75,352.71c33.61,0,67.45,11.41,97.83,33,30.07,21.36,54.13,51.23,67.74,84.09C1058.25,498.6,1061.73,528.9,1056.4,557.42Z"
        transform="translate(-283.46 -277.71)"
      />
      <path
        className={className}
        d="M413.13,649.88c-28.5-28.5-46.06-59.6-52.2-92.45-5.34-28.52-1.85-58.82,10.08-87.61,13.61-32.87,37.67-62.74,67.74-84.1,30.38-21.59,64.21-33,97.82-33,42.73,0,82.78,18.39,119.06,54.67l53,53,53-53C798,371.1,838,352.71,880.76,352.71c33.61,0,67.44,11.41,97.83,33,30.07,21.36,54.13,51.23,67.74,84.09,11.92,28.79,15.41,59.09,10.08,87.61-6.15,32.85-23.71,64-52.22,92.46L708.66,945.41Z"
        transform="translate(-283.46 -277.71)"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

2/ Import your component and add a className

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

import Heart from './Heart';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Heart className="red-heart" />
  );
}
```

3/ Create the class in your css file

**style.css**

```
.red-heart {
  fill: red;
}
```

Check the demo : [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-specific-path-element-in-a-svg-in-react?file=src/App.js)

Comment: I love you <3 Thanks a lot !